# Script con variables que ejecute Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Soy estudiante de ciclo superior de Informatica.

Quisiera saber si es factible crear un script (con variables de entorno) que sea capaz de crear un docker (wordpress) personalizado.

Me explico:

Tener un script con unos datos tipo nombre, BBDD, user, passw y este sea capaz de crear un contenedor de Docker con esos datos.

Que os parece?

Gracias

Comment: No sé qué significa crear un contenedor "con esos datos". Si te refieres a arrancar una imagen y pasarle como parámetros esos datos durante el arranque, puedes fácilmente hacerlo con un script y usar la opción `-E` de `docker` para asignar variables de entorno que serán visibles dentro del contenedor. Pero mejor que scripts yo usaría un `docker-compose.yaml` y la herramienta `docker-compose`

Comment: gracias compañero, ya lo probe y me funciona